# Emg signal plotter in python

Tags: python, signal-processing

- i have a problem im trying to code a python script that shows emg signal plotter but what im seing is choppy emg signal plotter similar to picture above but what i really want is the signal plotters to look like the picture below where there are multiple signal plotters windows and they're colorated.Thank you.[this is the plotter i have and its code is in the last picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM44p.jpg)

[This is how i want the plotter to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHtN8.jpg)
[This is the code of the plotter i have thats in the first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKJqb.jpg)

Comment: **DO NOT** post images of code,data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.  Images can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Also, refrain from posting links to problem definitions and/or explanations Instead, incorporate the explanation into your question directly.